# Is it possible to not wait for input when using Scanner.nextLine() or Scanner.hasNext() in console?

Tags: java, console, user-input

I am using Java to solve the SPOJ (http://www.spoj.pl) problems and a lot of them are, obviously, using console input. The problem is, some of them don't say how many lines of  input there will be so it is up to me to close the program when there is nothing more. I am using Scanner:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
```

Unfortunately, it will not read the next line, but... wait for user input and THEN get the next line. This is also true for

```
s.hasNext();
```

so I do not know when to finish the program. Is there a way to read the lines of input WITHOUT waiting for it?

Comment: Not sure how can solve this. Usually you can just get the user to pass in a KEYWORD which you program knows indicates that it is the end of input

Comment: maybe you can try to read char by char

Comment: This could help you out http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue153.html

Comment: How is the console input given to the program?

Comment: I'm pasting the code to the site and they compile and run it locally, I think their program just types in the input, although I'm not sure.

Comment: You HAVE TO know exactly how the input is given... I think roliu is right, post on the forums or something... Are you sure it is not your fault? they use a Pentium 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems are designed to take too much time if you are not using a smart algorithm to find the solution.I would recommend :

- First, to know ***exactly*** how the input is given
- Then, understand ***exactly*** what `NZEC` (and other error codes) means. They have a [forum](http://www.spoj.pl/forum/)
- At this point, if your program is still killed while it is executed it just means that you need to find a better algorithm which will take less time.

What I would recommend is to pass an input stream as parameter for the function doing 
the work and give a file as an optional parameter for your program. Create several files inputs, test your code on the file input streams, and try to detect what influence the running time of your program.

Comment: Thanks, I read some more info on NZEC and I learned that for Java it means there was an exception. So I put it in try-catch and... it worked. Although I am not really sure why is that.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much a standard in competition programming problems for them to give a specification for the input (as I'm sure you know). I looked through a few of the problems on the website and they were all specified. Do you have a link to a problem without a complete specification?

In that case, it would be useful to email the admins to update the spec. Besides that, `Scanner.hasNextLine()` should return false if you've reached the end of the input.

*Update* The input is being piped from a file so `hasNextLine()` should function as desired. Has it not worked for you so far? Are you sure your code isn't taking too long in some other way?

Comment: The result is NZEC which I believe means that my program didn't close. It happens even when I use `while(Scanner.hasNext())` so I think it means that it waits endlessly for input. This is also what happens when I run it locally. Maybe I shouldn't use `System.in`?

Answer (score 0):

you are going about this incorrectly. you must continue reading until there is no more input, where the end of input is defined as null. time spent waiting for a timeout WILL cause your code to fail spoj tests - spoj is very strict about speed.

say i give you the following problem:

given a list of integers, each on its own line, print out the sum of all the integers.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

we do not know if or when more input will come. the key is that there is not someone sitting there typing in the numbers. input is piped to the program directly from a file and will end in null (as files tend to do).

what should work for spoj is the following:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String line = "";
    int sum = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

if there is some weird spoj case that I am missing, i request you comment this with the spoj problem and i will tell you how to go about reading the input. definitely NOT timers or threads or any silly stuff.

Answer (score -1):

make a timer variable

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
// Start timer here
String str = s.nextLine();
//If a next line is read, reset timer.
```

add an event to the timer so that if it expires, your program will close.